# How do I parse a number from a String that may have a leading zero?

Tags: ruby, string, date, types

In ruby I am parsing a date in the following format: 24092008.
I want to convert each section (year, month, date) into a number.

I have split them up using a regex which produces three Strings which I am passing into the Integer constructor.

```
  date =~ /^([\d]{2})([\d]{2})([\d]{4})/
  year = Integer($3)
  month = Integer($2)
  day = Integer($1)
```

When it hits the month line it crashes as follows:

```
`Integer': invalid value for Integer: "09" (ArgumentError)
```

It took me a while to realise that it's interpreting the leading zero as Octal and 09 is not a valid Octal number (it works fine with "07").

Is there an elegant solution to this or should I just test for numbers less than 10 and remove the zero first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not familiar with regexes, so forgive me if this answer's off-base.  I've been assuming that $3, $2, and $1 are strings.  Here's what I did in IRB to replicate the problem:

```
irb(main):003:0> Integer("04")
=> 4
irb(main):004:0> Integer("09")
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer: "09"
    from (irb):4:in `Integer'
    from (irb):4
    from :0
```

But it looks like .to_i doesn't have the same issues:

```
irb(main):005:0> "04".to_i
=> 4
irb(main):006:0> "09".to_i
=> 9
```

Comment: @Atiaxi: the 'invalid value' is thrown because "09" isn't a valid octal number. A leading zero typically means it is in octal, and 0-7 are the valid digits in octal. :obj.to_i converts assuming base-10.

Comment: `String#to_i` will ignore trailing non-numeric characters. `"123abc".to_i # => 123`. This might not be desirable

Comment: You can specify base-10 explicitly in Ruby 1.9: `Integer("09", 10) #=> 9`

Answer (score 9):

## Specify base 10

Tell Ruby explicitly that you want to interpret the string as a base 10 number.

```
Integer("09", 10) # => 9
```

This is **better than `.to_i` if you want to be strict**.

```
"123abc".to_i # => 123
Integer("123abc", 10) # => ArgumentError
```

### How I figured this out

In `irb`, `method(:Integer)` returns `#<Method: Object(Kernel)#Integer>`. That told me that `Kernel` owns this method, and I looked up the documentation on Kernel. [The method signature](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) shows that it takes a base as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `(0([\d])|([1-9][\d]))` in place of `([\d]{2})`
You may have to use $2, $4, and $5 in place of $1, $2, $3.

Or if your regexp supports `(?:...)` then use `(?:0([\d])|([1-9][\d]))`

Since ruby takes its regexp from perl, this latter version should work.

Comment: Problem here is that now you have too many matches. I think the to_i approach is the best in this case, by the kiss principle

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking any integer with leading 0 directly. Eg:

`Integer("08016") #=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "08016"`

Create a method to check and rescue for leading 0:

```
def is_numeric(data)
  _is_numeric = true if Integer(data) rescue false

  # To deal with Integers with leading 0
  if !_is_numeric
    _is_numeric = data.split("").all?{|q| Integer(q.to_i).to_s == q }
  end

  _is_numeric
end
```

> is_numeric("08016") #=> true
> is_numeric("A8016") #=> false