# How to validate that a string is a year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Ruby/RoR - The year is a string in the model/view. How do I validate that the user entered string is a valid gregorian calendar year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the cost of a tiny bit of cleverness/regexp magic, something like the following will allow you to test not only for whether a string is numeric (the first criteria for being a valid year) but for whether it falls within a particular range of years:

```
def is_valid_year?(date_str, start=1900, end=2099)
  date_str.grep(/^(\d)+$/) {|date_str| (start..end).include?(date_str.to_i) }.first
end
```

The above function returns `nil` for any string with non-numeric characters, `false` for those which are numeric but outside the provided range, and `true` for valid year strings.

Comment: +1-Wow nice work ... i think i should also look deep into Regex!

Comment: A few (pedantic?) notes: You can't name a method parameter end (as that's a reserved keyword), and this method will return false for the string " 1999", so you may want to call .strip before .grep.

Comment: @Greg: good point on the parameter name -- I obviously extracted this from an IRb session, not a full source file, so names were changed in the browser window. Calling `#strip` might be a useful relaxation of the validation rule, but it would depend on the application.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like a more direct question is: how do you validate that the user enters a string corresponding to a number between 1582 and 2500 (say). You can do this like this:

```
 date_string.scan(/\D/).empty? and (1582..2500).include?(date_string.to_i)
```

that way, you can choose what a sensible year is, too - for example, is 800 really a valid answer in your application? or 3000?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Date.strptime(date_str, "%Y").gregorian?
```

Note that this will throw exceptions if the string is in an unexpected format.  Another (more forgiving) option, is:

```
Date.new(date_str.to_i).gregorian?
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer by @rcoder will not be working as i tested on rails 4+
.
i made another simple one.

```
def is_valid_year? year
  return false if year.to_i.to_s != year
  year.strip.to_i.between?(1800, 2999)
end
```

The first line to not accept characters, you can also change the range between as you wish

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.parse(string_of_date).gregorian?
```

Also, have a look at the documentation for the [Date class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html).

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion doesn't work if the input is 1999 or 2005! Date.parse. is looking for YYYYMMDD, I think.

Comment: Ah. I hadn't realized you only wanted the year (even though it says so right in the question!). My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to parse an integer from a string is a pretty common question for Ruby. Probably because there's no perfect approach. Maybe it deserves its own tag!

[Safe integer parsing in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274/safe-integer-parsing-in-ruby)

[Test if a string is basically an integer in quotes using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235863/test-if-a-string-is-basically-an-integer-in-quotes-using-ruby)

[How do I get the second integer in a Ruby string with to_i?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060300/how-do-i-get-the-second-integer-in-a-ruby-string-with-toi)

[Extract and multiple integers from user-input string in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892562/extract-and-multiple-integers-from-user-input-string-in-ruby)

[How can I convert an entire line of input into an integer in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922151/how-can-i-convert-an-entire-line-of-input-into-an-integer-in-ruby)

[How do I parse a number from a String that may have a leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146668/how-do-i-parse-a-number-from-a-string-that-may-have-a-leading-zero)

[Retrieve number from the string pattern using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694176/retrieve-number-from-the-string-pattern-using-regular-expression)